# How to remove gap between columns with grid-auto-flow: row dense

Tags: css, grid

I´m trying to make columns responsive and acording to the screen width the columns change from 3 to 1 column. The problem is the div not fit the empty space. The grid-auto-flow: row dense should work but no success.

```css
.frontpage_cats {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  column-gap: 1em;
  max-width: 620px;
  margin: 15px auto;
  grid-auto-flow: row dense;
}

.cats_colums ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: none;
  padding: 5px 8px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.cats_colums ul li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:530px) {
  .frontpage_cats {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width:375px) {
  .frontpage_cats {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="frontpage_cats">
  <div class="cats_colums cats_col1">
    <ul>
      <li>Column 1</li>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
      <li>5</li>
      <li>6</li>
      <li>7</li>
      <li>8</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
      <li>5</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="cats_colums cats_col2">
    <ul>
      <li>Column 2</li>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
      <li>5</li>
      <li>6</li>
      <li>7</li>
      <li>8</li>
      <li>9</li>li>10</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
      <li>5</li>
      <li>6</li>
      <li>7</li>
      <li>8</li>
      <li>9</li>
      <li>10</li>
      <li>11</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="cats_colums cats_col3">
    <ul>
      <li>Column 3</li>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
      <li>5</li>
      <li>6</li>
      <li>7</li>
      <li>8</li>
      <li>9</li>
      <li>10</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
      <li>5</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

This code with too many ul li reproduces exactally what it is on my website.

https://jsfiddle.net/adrianocos/sfrv7dma/

Ps. Verify the columns when screen is under 530px. Between que column 1 and 3 gap is there.

I did many researchs and find grid-auto-flow: row dense as solution but not workinkg here.

Thank for any help!

[image]

Comment: There was two coments for this question and it desapear. very strange. Thank you the person that has give the way! I forgot the name. sorry.